# Call multiple actions jointly in React Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-actions

I am learning React Redux. My Action is like below

```
import Axios from 'axios';

export const getAddress = valueModal => dispatch => {
  return Axios.get('/api/address')
    .then(response => {
      var addressData = response.data;
      dispatch({
        type: 'getAddresses',
        payload: { addressData, valueModal }
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

export const uploadImage = (formData, id, config) => dispatch => {
  return Axios.post('/api/address/upload', formData, config)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'uploadImage',
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
    });
};

export default { getAddress, addAddress, uploadImage };
```

My Reducer is like below

```
const initialState = {
    address: {}
};

const addressReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'getAddresses': {
            return {
              controlModal: action.payload.valueModal,
              address: action.payload.addressData
            };
        }
        case 'uploadImage': {
            return {
                uploadImage: action.payload
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default addressReducer;
```

I would like to call `getAddresses` and `uploadImage` jointly. How can I do that ?

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to call them jointly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
const initialState = {
    address: {}
};

const addressReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'getAddresses': {
            return {
              ...state,
              controlModal: action.payload.valueModal,
              address: action.payload.addressData
            };
        }
        case 'uploadImage': {
            return {
                ...state,
                uploadImage: action.payload
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export default addressReducer;
```

You need to spread the object state out otherwise there is never a reference to the state before the update.

The object spread syntax lets you use the spread `...` operator to copy enumerable properties from one object to another in a more succinct way.

Comment: Glad I could help.